# SQL Query - associate results from one query to another query that does not have a related field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

Need some help/direction...

I have a query that gives me a list of inventory needed at many locations... 
-Location
-SKU
-QtyNeeded

I have another query that gives me a list of available inventory...and the inventory is serialized (unique numbers).
-SKU
-SerialNumber

The end result that I'm trying to get to...is to run a query that will assign available SerialNumbers to a location based on the quantity they need for each sku that they need.

Example...

Query1
Store1    SKU1     2
Store1    SKU2     1
Store2    SKU1     1
Store2    SKU2     2

Query2
SKU1     serial1
SKU1     serial2
SKU1     serial3
SKU1     serial4
SKU1     serial5
SKU2     serial6
SKU2     serial7
SKU2     serial8
SKU2     serial9
SKU2     serial10
SKU3     serial11
SKU3     serial12

Desired result…
Store1     SKU1     serial1
Store1     SKU1     serial2
Store1     SKU2     serial6
Store2     SKU1     serial3
Store2     SKU2     serial7
Store2     SKU2     serial8

Thanks!
Darin

Comment: In the desired results, are serial1 and serial2 the same number repeated? Obviously, you have to join these tables on the SKU, but it's not clear if you're trying to repeat the results for the number of QtyNeeded. If the desired results are distinct, you are just looking at a regular join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a recursive CTE(common table expression) for query 1 to turn

```
Store1 SKU1 2
Store1 SKU2 1
Store2 SKU1 1
Store2 SKU2 2
```

into

```
Store1 SKU1 2 1
Store1 SKU1 2 2
Store2 SKU1 1 3
Store1 SKU2 1 1
Store2 SKU2 2 2
Store2 SKU2 2 3
```

Then use `ROW_NUMBER () OVER ()` to add row numbers to query 2:

```
SKU1 serial1 1
SKU1 serial2 2
SKU1 serial3 3
SKU1 serial4 4
SKU1 serial5 5
SKU2 serial6 1
SKU2 serial7 2
SKU2 serial8 3
SKU2 serial9 4
SKU2 serial10 5
SKU3 serial11 1
SKU3 serial12 2
```

You should then be able to join the results together on the new row numbers you added and the SKU #.

**EDIT -----------**

Adding CTE example:

```
;with LocationQtyData as(
select
    location, sku, qtyneeded, 1 as rowNum
from #LocationQtys
union all
select
    #LocationQtys.location, #LocationQtys.sku, #LocationQtys.qtyneeded, rowNum + 1 as rowNum
from #LocationQtys
join LocationQtyData
    on LocationQtyData.location = #LocationQtys.location
    and LocationQtyData.sku = #LocationQtys.sku
where LocationQtyData.rowNum < #LocationQtys.qtyneeded
)

select * from LocationQtyData
order by
location, sku, qtyneeded, rowNum
```

Replace #LocationQtys with your table name. Notice in the "union all" portion of the query, we can reference the name of the CTE ("LocationQtyData") to recursively go through it. The where clause tells it when to terminate the recursion.

Comment: liebs19...this concept makes sense to me.  I'm good on adding the Row_Number on query2...but, I've not written a CTE expression before (let alone a recursive statement) which is required with query1.  I'll do some googling.  But, hoping you can give some guidance with that, as well.

Comment: See the edit to the original post for a sample of what the CTE could be.

Comment: Thanks liebs19!  This got me on the right track...the only thing I had to add was adding a Row_Number.  I couldn't get the Recursive CTE to output "rowNum" by sku...as the qtyneeded was tied to the store.  So, the rowNum would reset to 1 for each store for each sku.  But, the R(CTE) did output the correct number of rows for each store/sku/qtyneeded.  So, then it was easy to add in Row_Number (partition by SKU orderby SKU) in the select statement.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I was able to guide you to your solution.